# How do I merge my current kali partition with a recently created one that I added on seperate HDD?

Tags: partition, kali-linux

My primary kali partition is running low on space and I have formatted a 1TB HDD with an EXT4 file system and a GPT partition table. I am wanting to merge the two together. They are on two seperate HDD's. I am not sure if I will have to configure raid 0 for this or if there is another way. I am currently dual booting win 10 and kali but using separate hard drives for all.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to merge the partition rather than using the external drive for e.g. /home?

Comment: I have all my whole kali OS on my smaller drive and I just want to add more space to that

Comment: its not an external, I am wanting more space for the whole OS

Comment: Do I just clone the smaller drive onto the bigger drive?

Comment: In case that is an option, I recommend cloning the smaller drive onto the bigger one. The result will be easier to handle and less error-prone.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with `rsync` but you have to read more and know what are the risks. Also you can do it with LVM. Create a volume group which contains only  the new drive then move the data from the old to the new, then wipe the old one and add it to the volume group.
Those links might give you a starting point
[Link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117014/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-merge-and-home)
[Link2](https://serverfault.com/questions/241987/convert-full-hard-drive-to-lvm-without-external-storage)

Comment: Technically, this answer is correct. I recommand dd or better e2image -rap for copying the entire partition instead of rsync. As op can clone the drive, I recommend doing that. LVM is less easy to use.

Comment: Yes, I forgot `dd`, probably will be easier with it.